# Can't find the C# class "X509SigningCredentials". Has X509SigningCredentials gone out of ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, token

I'm working on a Token Service project in ASP.Net core. I'm implementing a previous service into this one. It uses `X509SigningCredentials` from the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` namespace. However, this doesn't appear to be there any more?

Is this because I'm using ASP.Net core, or has this been changed to something else?

Answer (score 0):

That same problem. I've found the solution by reimplementing 
[the original source code of X509SigningCredentials](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/Tokens/X509SigningCredentials.cs,91722fb503164b48)

```
new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithmStrings.RsaSha256Signature);
```